# why is this resource not updating the view after using $delete method

Tags: angularjs

In my angular app I have a controller as follows:

```
function TemplateListControl($scope, TemplateService){
    $scope.templates = TemplateService.get(); // Get objects from resource

    // Delete Method
    $scope.deleteTemplate = function(id){
        $scope.templates.$delete({id: id});
    }
}
```

Within the view I have a table thats bound to `templates` model. as follows:

```
<table ng-model="templates">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th style="width:40%">Title</th>
            <th style="width:40%">controls</th>
        </tr>
    <thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="template in templates">
            <td>
                <!-- Link to template details page -->
                <a href="#/template/[[template.id]]">
                    [[template.title]]
                </a>
            </td>
            <td>
                <!-- Link to template details page -->
                <a class="btn btn-primary btn-small"
                   href="#/template/[[template.id]]">Edit
                </a>
                <!-- Link to delete this template -->
                <a class="btn btn-primary btn-small"
                   ng-click="deleteTemplate(template.id)">Delete
                </a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Now when I click on the delete link in the above template, It calls the `deleteTemplate` method and a successful `DELETE` call is made to the REST api. But the view does not get updated until it is refreshed and `$scope.templates = TemplateService.get();` is initiated again. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also have to update client side so modify your source code as below

```
 ng-click="deleteTemplate($index)">


$scope.delete = function ( idx ) {
  var templateid = $scope.templates[idx];

  API.Deletetemplate({ id: templateid.id }, function (success) {
    $scope.templates.splice(idx, 1);
  });
};
```

Comment: and how do we know if the asynchronous call to REST api succeeded ? I am quiet sure angular's resource should update the view accordingly on its own. If we manually have to update the data on client side, we'll also need to do the error handling manually, which to me seems like going in the opposite direction.

Comment: Could you share fiddle please

Answer (score 3):

I prefer using promises instead of callback. Promises are the new way to handle asynchronous processes. You can inspect the result using a a promise right after it came back from the server.

```
//Controller
myApp.controller('MyController',
    function MyController($scope, $log, myDataService) {

 $scope.entities = myDataService.getAll();
 $scope.removeEntity = function (entity) {       
        var promise = myDataService.deleteEntity(entity.id);
        promise.then(
            // success
            function (response) {
                $log.info(response);
                if (response.status == true) {
                    $scope.entities.pop(entity);
                }
            },
            // fail
            function (response) {
                $log.info(response);
                // other logic goes here
            }
        );
    };
 });

 //DataService
 myApp.factory('myDataService', function ($log, $q, $resource) {

return {
    getAll: function () {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        $resource('/api/EntityController').query(
            function (meetings) {
                deferred.resolve(meetings);
            },
            function (response) {
                deferred.reject(response);
            });

        return deferred.promise;
    },

    deleteEntity: function (entityId) {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        $resource('/api/EntityController').delete({ id: entityId},
            function (response) {
                deferred.resolve(response);
            },
            function (response) {
                deferred.reject(response);
            });

        return deferred.promise;
    }
   };
});

//Web API Controller
public class MeetingController : BaseApiController
{
   // .... code omited 

   public OperationStatus Delete(int entityId)
    {
        return _repository.Delete(_repository.Single<MyEntity>(e => e.EntityID == entityId));
    }
}
```

Note: $log, $q, $resource are built in services. Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

You could pass a callback function to $resource.$delete

```
function TemplateListControl($scope, TemplateService){
  $scope.templates = TemplateService.get(); // Get objects from resource

  // Delete Method
  $scope.deleteTemplate = function(id){
    TemplateService.$delete({id: id}, function(data) {
      $scope.templates = data;
    });
  }
}
```

**Attention**
If your REST APIs delete function returns an array you have to set isArray: true in your Angular $resource to avoid a AngularJS $resource error - *TypeError: Object # has no method 'push'*

```
$resource(URL, {}, {
  delete: {method:'DELETE', isArray: true}
});
```